# deploying war on jboss as7

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm trying to deploy a war file on jboss as7 using the maven plugin but it doesn't seem to be working. In my pom.xml I have the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.Final</version>
        </plugin>
```

and I'm running it using the external tools in Eclipse with these arguments:

```
eclipse:eclipse clean install jboss-as:deploy
```

The console output from the maven build shows no errors and says everything was deployed correctly however when I try to access a page in the war I get a 404 error. There are no errors in the logs either.

I noticed that the standalone/deployments folder is empty so I copied the war file into here and I can access the pages with no problems.

So the question is why is my application not deployed correctly, or if it is why can I not access it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. I was using the URL <project_name>/<page> rather than <war_name>/<page>. So because maven was appending the version number to the project name there was nothing at that URL. Silly mistake that took far too long to figure out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using the URL `<project_name>/<page>` rather than `<war_name>/<page>`. So because maven was appending the version number to the project name there was nothing at that URL. Silly mistake that took far too long to figure out!